# Windows 10 - All desktop icons shifted on the left side after startup

Tags: desktop-icons

Today,not for the first time,after startup I had all desktop icons on the left side.

Usually,they are on left,right side and on the top of the screen.

Please,can someone explain to me what happened, how to avoid this and when it

happen what can be done? to keep their original positions (aligned to the grid).

Update:

I have always had "align icons to the grid"selected,because it doesn't work in other

ways.Now some icons are not aligned to the grid,when I save something, and I

have to move them in the right position (holding the left and not the right

button).

Thank you

Comment: Did Windows or the PC crash or get shut down improperly before you started it today?

Comment: @K.A,nothing happened before

Comment: the proper way for punctuations is one space after the symbol (except for opening brackets/quotes where a single space is added before)

Comment: @magicandre1981,what do you think about this problem?Thank you

Comment: I use 3rd party tools, too: http://www.midiox.com/index.htm?http://www.midiox.com/desktoprestore.htm

Comment: @magicandre1981,thank you very much.Have you only "align icons to the grid"selected?Is it true that this problem is caused by Creator Update?

Comment: I still use Win8 and use the tool to have a fixed Icon layout

Answer (score 1):

On your desktop, use your mouse to right click, you should have this window popping up, hover down to **view***, if your **Auto arrange icons** and **Align icons to grid** [image: windows]

are checked like the one in the picture above, uncheck them both so that you can have this picture beside: [image].

After which you can refresh your computer.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: ,I have always had "Align icons to grid" checked.If I understand well,first I have to uncheck and if it happen again  have I to "Refresh"?

Answer (score 1):

I have has this problem for 18 months and have tried all of things that various parties (including Microsoft) have suggested, with no success. In my case it appears to be something to do with screen resolution and I suspect its a mismatch between Windows and my graphics driver. The problem started when I changed my monitor to one with a higher resolution.

I have given up on trying to solve it but now use the (free) program 'Desktop Restore' which works brilliantly. Now when it defaults to the left I just hit Desktop Restore and it goes back to my saved desktop.

Icon Restorer is also an alternative I have used but that stopped working properly after 4 months in that it would not revert the icons back to the saved position for more that a couple of seconds. It worked well while it lasted though.